# Where to find free-to-use, complex test databases?

Tags: database, oracle, test-data, sample-data

I need a database for testing a data masking solution. Any database would do (Oracle/MSSQL flavor). I just need the schema / db definition. I have tools to generate data records. The magnitude of database I am looking should have 30 odd tables with 30 odd columns in each table - a HUGE database.

Do freely available complex database /schema definitions exist on the internet? If yes, where do I find them?

Comment: Why is having 30 tables and 30 columns per table a HUGE database? By that measure I'm working on a REALLY HUGE GIGANTIC database right now :)

Comment: @Jeffrey send me your schema :) I can use it!

Comment: Sorry Jay, it's proprietary ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various iterations of the [AdventureWorks schema](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) for SQL 2005/2008 available.

Answer (score 3):

Not as complex as you want but [Chinook DB](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/) is a free sample database that supports Oracle among others.

Comment: I guess I will need a more complex schema

Answer (score 1):

The good ol' NorthWind. Here r the oracle scripts http://jagchat.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!41050F68F010A662!758.entry